Telegram qr api
Всем привет, есть такая проблема уже несколько часов не могу решить
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def generate_qr():
    try:
        await client.start()

        qr_login = await client.qr_login()

        print(qr_login.expires)

        qr_url = qr_login.url

        if qr_url:
            img = qrcode.make(qr_url)
            print(qr_url)
            img.save("login_qr.png")
            print("QR code saved as login_qr.png")

            user = await qr_login.wait()
            print(f"Logged in as: {user.first_name}")

            print(f"Token: {urlsafe_b64encode(qr_login.token).decode('utf-8')}")
        else:
            print("Failed to generate QR code URL.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

client.loop.run_until_complete(generate_qr())


Код генерирует qr код и ждет пока его отксанируют чтобы пользователь авторизовался и наш клиент мог обращаться к тeлеграм апи от пользователя
Exporting a login token
First of all, auth.exportLoginToken must be called by the app that wants to log in to an existing Telegram account.
The method will return an auth.loginToken constructor, containing a binary login token and an expiration date (usually 30 seconds).

The login token must be encoded using base64url, embedded in a tg://login?token=base64encodedtoken URL and shown in the form of a QR code to the user.
After the expiration of the current QR code, the auth.exportLoginToken method must be recalled and a new QR code must be generated automatically.

Accepting a login token
In order to log in, the QR code must be scanned and accepted by an already logged-in Telegram app using auth.acceptLoginToken.
The token must be extracted from the tg://login URI and base64url-decoded before using it in the method.

Possible errors returned by the method are:

400 - AUTH_TOKEN_INVALID, an invalid authorization token was provided
400 - AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRED, the provided authorization token has expired and the updated QR-code must be re-scanned
400 - AUTH_TOKEN_ALREADY_ACCEPTED, the authorization token was already used
The method will return an authorization object, containing info about the app and session that we just authorized.

Confirming (importing) the login token
After the logged-in app calls auth.acceptLoginToken and accepts the login token, the app that is trying to login will receive an updateLoginToken update, which should trigger a second call to the auth.exportLoginToken method.

This second call should then return an auth.loginTokenSuccess constructor, indicating successful login, essentially allowing further authorized interaction with the API.

If, however, there is a DC mismatch between the two apps, auth.loginTokenMigrateTo is returned instead, to which the app that is trying to login should respond by calling auth.importLoginToken with the specified token, to the specified DC.

This call should then finally return a auth.loginTokenSuccess constructor.

В документации мы видим, что клиент  во время сканирования qr кода на самом деле отправляет запрос (токен который написан в qr коде) к методу
auth.acceptLoginToken

только проблема в том что во время скана я получаю ответ
AUTH_TOKEN_ALREADY_ACCEPTED

т.е. кто то уже этому методу отправил токен. Кто еще сталкивался с такой проблемой можете подсказать что я делаю не так?
